# Shell command How to cut multiple lines of string and move them to other part in same file

Tags: regex, shell, awk, sed

I have some text in a file someText.txt

```
{
  someOtherTexts
  debug {
     minifyEnabled true
     shrinkResources false
     {
       other
     }
  }

  release {
     print()
  }
}
```

How can I copy the content in debug closure and move them into release closure, which becomes below.

```
{
  someOtherTexts
  debug {
     minifyEnabled true
     shrinkResources false
     {
       other
     }
  }

  release {
     minifyEnabled true
     shrinkResources false
     {
       other
     }
     print()
  }
}
```

I have tried with

```
#search the next two lines after match
qaConfig=$(awk '/qa {/{x=NR+2;next}(NR<=x){print}' ./someText.txt)

#append after match
sed -i '' "/release {/a\\
${qaConfig}" ./someText.txt
```

But it throws error

```
sed: 3: "/release {/a\

         ...": invalid command code T
```

Any approaches are welcomed.

Updated:
In real case, I have actually got inner bracket in my file so I have added it to my example as well. That's why I had to go with the fixed number after match approach.

updated:
Thank you for your solutions, now things gets a bit more complicated. I have to add a bracket surrounding all the text. Is there a way to deal with that too? thanks

Comment: Your example suggests the text file is actually structured with some kind of syntax.  Depending on how many such files you need to modify, and depending on how variable their content is from your exact example, you may need to write a proper parser to find and change the relevant section(s) of input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a flag when encountering `debug {` and keep appending the lines to a buffer if the flag is set, until the flag is unset by encountering a `}`, and output the buffer when `release {` is encountered:

```
awk '/release {/{$0=$0s}1;/}/{--d}i&&d>=i{s=s ORS$0}d<i{i=0}/{/{++d}/debug {/{i=d}'
```

`awk` doesn't support writing the output directly back to the same file, however, so you would have to write it to a temporary file first before overwriting the original file with it:

```
awk '...' input.txt > temp.txt && mv temp.txt input.txt
```

EDIT: As @anubhava pointed out, it is possible to write back to the same file if you're using `gawk`, with the `-i inplace` option.

EDIT 2: Also borrowing @anubhava's code to append lines to a string buffer rather than an array.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I would probably got other closure(brakets) inside it, so I can not use } to determine the end, that's why I go with fixed number approach. The other question is, this doesn't seem to write the output back to the file?

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer to cope with nested closures then.

Comment: Thank you. does this work when there is an outside closure? I have updated my question. sorry, I was trying to find a flexible solution but obviously indention is really import here

Comment: I see. I've updated my answer to cope with an outside closure then.

Comment: beautiful solution!

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` may work:

```
awk '/^}/{p=0} p{s = s ORS $0} /^debug[ \t]*{/{p=1}
/^release[ \t]*{/{$0 = $0 s} 1' file
```

```
someOtherTexts
debug {
   minifyEnabled true
   shrinkResources false
   {
     other
   }
}

release {
   minifyEnabled true
   shrinkResources false
   {
     other
   }
   print()
}
```

To store output to same file use:

```
awk '/^}/{p=0} p{s = s ORS $0} /^debug[ \t]*{/{p=1}
/^release[ \t]*{/{$0 = $0 s} 1' file > file.tmp && mv file.tmp file
```

Comment: does this write the change back to the file. btw, I have updated the question, so I can't really search by brackets.

Comment: I gott error running your commands: awk: unknown option -i ignored

awk: can't open file -v
 source line number 1

Comment: that's a beautiful solution. Can I please add one more requirement, If I have a bracket surrounding all the text wich means an indentation is added to each line. how can I make it to work with your commands.

Comment: I posted a working solution twice, once for your original problem and then the present one for your edited question. This is considered bad practice to keep changing your problem after getting answers for original problem. What stopped you to post this requirement upfront in original question?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^  debug {/{h;:a;n;/^  }/b;H;ba};/^  release {/{p;g;D}' file
```

If the current line begins `debug` gather up the lines until the  line before the closing `}`  for this segment of code.

If the current line begins `release`, print that line, replace it by the gathered collection and then ditch the first of these lines.

This has the effect of appending the gathered lines (less the first) following the line beginning `release`.